# Does China hide its original economic information?

Tags: economy, china

Is the economic information released by Chinese government real?

Do they have a tendency to skew that information?

If yes, why, and how do they do that?

Comment: Questions about whether or not a specific claim is true is usually better suited for [skeptics.SE](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/). But they only deal with claims from notable sources, so a statement by "some random person" would not qualify. But if you can't find a similar statement from a notable source with some searching, you already have your answer about how much that person knows about the Chinese economy (either more than everyone else in the world or nothing at all).

Comment: "So, India is going to be the largest economy by 2030 surpassing China." No, that's very unlikely. China's economy is currently 5x India's.

Comment: China has a rep for skewing its economic statistics, but the skew isn't cumulative over time.

Comment: On the other hand China also has an incentive to skewing its data to the lesser side so as to continue to pass as a developing country. In practice Chinese authorities do both.

Comment: Just because it's impossible to mathematically test the answer to this question doesn't make it opinion based. There's plenty of economic analysts with answers to this question. Here's an example: https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2014-04-10/china-fake-data-to-skew-more-export-numbers